# What is wrong with my usage of the super format?

Tags: java, super

What is wrong with this line of coding for java?

```
public class ClassB extends ClassA {
    int attributeB;
    public ClassB(int a) {
        atrributeB = a;
        super(40);
    }
}
```

Comment: What language are you using, Java?

Answer (score 1):

super has to be always called first in the constructor

Comment: or in any overriden function, If I remember correctly.

Comment: @ItamarG3 Super has an entirely different meaning in methods, and there it doesn't need to be the first statement.